# How do I replace Unity?

Tags: unity, compiz, lubuntu

I wanted to use Ubuntu 12.04 for its long term support. But I cannot stand Unity. I cannot find a way to replace it with compizconfig, so I tried replacing it with Lubuntu.
When I restarted my computer started to load lubuntu, then just went right on with ubuntu as if nothing had happened. Likewise, it shows lubuntu when it shuts down. What is the deal?
I'm confused here, is ubuntu 12.04 supposed to be an operating system or a desktop interface? Can I even run ubuntu with a Lubuntu interface?
Is there a way to do this in compizconfig that I should be doing instead?

Thanks everyone. Now how do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: If you want the gnome classic desktop see this question [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/58172/107450) or take a look at one other the other members of the family. [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/), [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/), [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download) or [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/download/).  These are all fully supported here and don't have the Unity desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

then at login click the little ubuntu icon next to your name.
It'll take you to a menu like this: [image: desktop-environments]

Click LXDE.

Answer (score 1):

The Lubuntu components for version 12.04 have reached end-of-life so you will, from now onward, not get updates to the components specific to Lubuntu:

> Lubuntu 12.04 is not an LTS (5 years support), but a standard release
>   that is supported for 18 months (if you would like to change this
>   please feel free to contact the developers to offer assistance in this
>   area).

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu).

Look here for the possibility of Lubuntu 14.04 being a [long-term support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) version.